# angularJS background-image loading error

Tags: angularjs

I set a background-image for a div container over url(...).

```
<div ng-cloak class="userProfileItem userProfileImage" style="background-image: url(api/files/profileimage/{{vm.currentUser.profileImagePath}}/)">
...
```

Sometimes (not always) it can happen than I get the following Browser Error:

> "NetworkError: 403 Forbidden - http://localhost:8082/api/files/profileimage/%7B%7Bvm.currentUser.profileImagePath%7D%7D/"

Does anyone know how to solve this? I have tried it with **ng-cloak** but with no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ng-style` instead:

```
<div class="userProfileItem userProfileImage" ng-style="{'background-image': 'url(api/files/profileimage/{{vm.currentUser.profileImagePath}}/)'}">
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/bnf0ub4u/1/)